# Backing up Xbox 360 USB data then using then USB drive

Tags: windows-7, usb, backup, opensuse, xbox360

I have one USB drive available to me, its a 16GB Corsair which I use to save my Xbox 360 game data to. Now, I want to install OpenSUSE via a live USB, so I need to backup the data on the drive to my PC, create the live USB and install OpenSUSE (will be a dual boot with Windows) and then restore the Xbox data back to the drive.

Can I simply copy the data on the drive to my PC, format it (via Windows), create the live USB, install OpenSUSE, format it again (via Windows), format it using my Xbox and then copy the original files back to the drive?

Comment: Windows will be able to read the flash drive which was formatted by your Xbox.  You will have to transfer the data using your xbox to its hdd or another flash device.  Windows will simply request you format the data.

Comment: @Ramhound Thats going to be such a headache, I've got around 8GB of data on the USB drive and only 1.2GB available on my oldschool 20GB Xbox harddrive (and I can't really delete anything)

Comment: What do you want to hear.  Windows does not have the capability to read a partition that the Xbox 360 created.